# System.getProperty("os.name") and System.getProperty("os.version") returning windows 10, 10.0, in windows 11 machine

Tags: java, windows

[System.getProperty("os.name") and System.getProperty("os.version") returning windows 10, 10.0, in windows 11 machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuJBG.png)

If anyone knows Java code to get the Windows version without using any command, please help or attach Java code here.

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)
```

```java
class Demo
{
    public static void main(String g[])
    {
        System.out.println(" os name = "+System.getProperty("os.name"));
        System.out.println(" os version = "+System.getProperty("os.version"));
    }
}
```

output:

```
os name = Windows 10
os version = 10.0
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for things that are text. Post your source code and the output as code-formatted text.

Comment: What is your exact Java version

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_322"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 25.322-b06, mixed mode)

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8274840 says the fix was done in 8u331 (thus not in 8u321 or 8u322) (@MarkRotteveel)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I tested it using 1.8.0_332 (Temurin), and it still reported Windows 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Java 11 (11.0.15) and Java 17 (17.0.3), `System.getProperty("os.name")` returns `Windows 11`, but `"os.version"` still reports `10.0`, because that is actually the version that Microsoft (still) uses for Windows 11.

For example, Windows System Information reports:

OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version **10.0**.22000 Build 22000

This is similar to what is shown in your screenshot.

Java 8 (1.8.0_332) does unfortunately still report `Windows 10`. I have looked at the available system properties and environment variables in Java 8, but there doesn't seem to be a property or environment variable that allows you to detect you're using Windows 11 instead of Windows 10.

The list of backports of [JDK-8293124 Update OS detection code to recognize Windows 11](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8274840) suggests this should have been fixed in Java 8 update 8u311, 8u321, and 8u331. But given I still get the old result in 1.8.0_332 (Temurin) and 1.8.0_345 (Temurin), either this fix was reverted or only available in specific builds (e.g. Oracle's). It also lists the - not yet released - openjdk8u362, so maybe this fix will arrive in 1.8.0_362.